# Find and Replace is not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I was able to use "find and replace" to find out the specific text/number in excel sheet in the past.

But recently the function is not working, look like...

Alternately I need to copy+paste to new worksheet, then only can find the text.

Is there some setting issue or "find and replace" is not able to look for specific text/number in the cell contain formula?

[image: Fina and Replace snapshot]

Comment: The **Look in** list selection is incorrect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change "look in", instead of formulas, select values.

[image]

Comment: Ahhhh....how silly am I ...Thanks for clear my doubt.  It's working fine now.

Comment: This is such a common mistake now, I don't know why Excel changed this. You have to select "Values" every time.